# Change element index on click (both sides)

Tags: javascript

Im building a small feature. Basically on click "next" I need to loop through listOfImages, grab each src attribute and put it inside big image src. When "prev" is clicked - same but backwards. Its like super simple Lightbox. The only "thing" is that images are all around the page.

Structure looks like this:

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="big-image">
      <a href="somehref" class="picture">
         <img src="some_src" data-index="0">
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="more-viewes">
       <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="somehref" class="picture">
                <img src="some_src" data-index="1">
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="somehref" class="picture">
                <img src="some_src" data-index="2">
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="somehref" class="picture">
                <img src="some_src" data-index="3">
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="somehref" class="picture">
                <img src="some_src" data-index="4">
             </a>
          </li>
          ...
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

At the moment js looks like this:

```
var listOfImages = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");
var listOfImagesAmount = document.getElementsByClassName("picture").length;
for ( i = 0; i < listOfImages.length; i++) {
    //adding indexes in order to differentiate them
    listOfImages[i].dataset.index = I;
    //here im launching the big image with "right" "left arrows"
    listOfImages[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
       var srcAttr = this.lastChild.getAttribute('src');
       var elemIndex = this.dataset.index;
       var currentIndex = parseInt(elemIndex);
       //need to create html.
       document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += `<div id="img-popup-back"><</div><img id="fancyimg" src="`+ srcAttr +`" alt=""><div id="img-popup-next">></div>`;
       //"next" click event
       document.getElementById("img-popup-next").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var searchedIndex = currentIndex + 1;
            currentIndex = searchedIndex;
            if(currentIndex >= galleryItemsAmount - 2){
                currentIndex =- 1;
            }
            var checkElement = document.querySelector('[data-index="'+ searchedIndex +'"]');
            console.log(checkElement);//on index 0 this line showing a tag with an image inside as it should be.
            console.log(checkElement.lastChild); // but this one, on index 0, outputs "#text".
            if(checkElement){
                var nextSrc = checkElement.lastChild.getAttribute('src');
            }
            console.log(nextSrc);
            document.getElementById('fancyimg').setAttribute('src', nextSrc);
        });
        //"prev" click event
        document.getElementById("img-popup-back").addEventListener("click", function(){
            var searchedIndex = currentIndex - 1;
            currentIndex = searchedIndex;
            console.log(currentIndex);
            if(currentIndex < galleryItemsAmount - 2){
                currentIndex =+ 1;
            }
            var checkElement = document.querySelector('[data-index="'+ searchedIndex +'"]');
            if(checkElement){
                var nextSrc = checkElement.lastChild.getAttribute('src');
            }
            console.log(nextSrc);
            document.getElementById('fancyimg').setAttribute('src', nextSrc);
        });
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

There is a problem that I can't solve at the moment. So:

```
document.getElementById("img-popup-next").addEventListener("click", function(){
```

works fine until it hits element which index is 0. At this moment console is showing that:

checkElement.lastChild.getAttribute is not a function.

Element exist. Data-attribute is = 0. Cant see what the problem is.

If im clicking again - fine. It goes on.

Here is the same:

```
document.getElementById("img-popup-back").addEventListener("click", function(){
```

But I also would like to know how to start from the end of my HTMLCollection as soon as im on element index 0.
There is also one sad thing. IE 11 support is required

Comment: It's difficult to tell you anything without knowing your DOM structure, but my immediate guess would be that that element has no children? Have you tried throwing in `console.log(checkElement.lastChild)` and seeing if it's `null` for the error case? I also notice that you're using `=-` and `=+` as operators, which should be `-=` and `+=`. But maybe that's just a typo in the code you've written up here.

Comment: @Igid Thanks for your comment. Yep. I tried. if I console.log(checkElement.lastChild); -> for all elements output is image tag, but the one with index 0 = #text. I added DOM structure

Comment: that makes sense, then. The text doesn't have a `getAttribute` method. This node must be a special case which has text as well as an img tag. If you have an inconsistent DOM structure, `lastChild` probably isn't a great way to extract what you want. In fact you could grab the img tag as part of your query selector: `var nextImg = document.querySelector('[data-index="'+ searchedIndex +'"] img')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are relying on all of your html tags to store the data about your images.

You might be better off if you store the details of your images in javascript objects in an array.

For example

```
var imageDataArray = [];
var imgObj = {
    thumb_source: "/images/thumbs/000123.jpg",
    fancy_source: "/images/fancy/000123.jpg"
}
imageDataArray.push(imgObj);
```

I only inserted a single object into the array, but your onLoad function could populate all of your image objects into that array.  You'll notice that each object had src for both a thumbnail and a fancy

Then, rather than recreate the fancy img and the prev / next buttons... create them once in your html directly

```
<body>
    <div id="fancyImgContainer">
        <button id="prevBtn" onClick="imageShift(false)">Previous</button>
        <img id="fancyImg" src="">
        <button id="nextBtn" onClick="imageShift(true)">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbContainer">
    </div>
</body>
```

With that framework in mind, lets you can populate your thumbnails in your onLoad script by doing the following:

```
var thumbContainer = document.getElementById("thumbContainer");
for(var imgIndex = 0; imgIndex < imageDataArray.length; imgIndex++){
    var element = document.createElement("img");
    element.setAttribute('src',imageDataArray[imgIndex].thumb_source);
    element.setAttribute('onclick', 'setFancyImage(' + imgIndex + ')');
    thumbContainer.appendChild(element);
}
```

That should load up all of your thumbnails into the DOM.  Next, lets tackle the setFancyImage(index) function

```
var currentIndex = 0;
function setFancyImage(index){
    currentIndex = index;
    var fancyImg = document.getElementById('fancyImg');
    fancyImg.src = imageDataArray[currentIndex].fancy_source;
}
```

So now, when a thumbnail is clicked the fancy image src is updated.  Next we tackle the prev and next buttons by writing the imageShift(next) function

```
function imageShift(next){
    var numImages = imageDataArray.length;
    var shiftedIndex = 0;
    if(next){
        shiftedIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % numImages;
    } else {
        shiftedIndex = currentIndex - 1;
        if(shiftedIndex < 0){
            shiftedIndex += numImages;
        }
    }
    setFancyImage(shiftedIndex);
}
```

Now when either prev or next button is called, the function calls the setFancyImage() function but passes in the next or previous index.  At index = 0, if they click previous, it will see that the result is less than 0 and will set it to be the last index (ie numImages - 1).  If index is the last image and they click next, because the index will equal numImages, by taking % numImages the result will put shiftedIndex at 0.

Obviously all this is just concept... you'd need to adapt for your data and clean up the styling and what not

Comment: I really appreciate your time. Really. And it totally makes sense. Its just I can't edit html. Its the specific thing which bugs me a lot as well. + This is template page. So these src / href things loaded from DB for each specific product. It could be 4 of them here, but 25 of there there

Comment: completely understood.. you could still adapt this for your solution however... rather than populate array and then populate DOM, populate your array from the existing DOM.  you're already finding all the pictures and looping through to set listeners.. do the same but snag the img details into objects that you cram into an array... as you loop, you can even add id attributes to each img tag so they're easier to reference  later in script (ie when you want to easily assign your fancy img)

Comment: rather than have your next image script look for next DOM element then, it just has to look at next or previous array element... a much easier/cleaner approach.. especially when you wanna wrap the ends